# Nesting multiple divs with respect to one another

Tags: css

I have 3 `div` containers, namely, `#containerA`, `#containerB` and `#containerC`.

I want to position `#containerB` within `#containerA` and with respect to
`#containerA`'s coordinates. So, I set `#containerA` to have position:
relative and #containerB to have `position: absolute`. This way:

```
#containerA {
  position: relative;
}
#containerB {
  position: absolute;
}
```

This works fine between `#containerA` and `#containerB`. Now, I want to
make `#containerC` to be within and with respect to `#containerB`. However, setting the
`#containerB` to have `position: relative` would cause `#containerB` to lose
respect to `#containerA`. The code would look this way:

```
#containerA {
  position: relative;
}
#containerB {
  position: relative;
}
#containerC {
  position: absolute;
}
```

So, what should I do to get the `divs` to nest in one another in such a
way where `#containerC` is positioned with respect to `#containerB` and
`#containerB` is positioned with respect to `#containerA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: You set `#containerA` to have `position: relative;`; then `#containerB` and `#containerC` to have `position: absolute;`.

**Step 2**: You position `#containerB` using, let's say `left: 10px;` and `top: 20px;` (just examples, you can replace the values with whatever you wish).

**Step 3**: Let's say you want to position `#containerC` to be 5px from the top and 5px from the left of `#containerB`. Then you set `left: 5px;` and `top: 5px;`

Test: http://dabblet.com/gist/2788586 - element with cyan background has `position: static`. It can be set to relative.

Answer (score 0):

`position:relative` is used to set the origin point for **child** items that use `position:absolute`.

If you want B in respect to A then A would use `position:relative`, then B would be inside A with `position:absolute`. You should also specify positions: top,left or bottom, right.

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep it as `position: absolute` on `#containerB`, then setting `position: absolute` on `#containerC` will position it relative to `#containerB`

Comment: Suppose I have a subsequent div of `#containerD`. I do *not* want it to be positioned with respect to `#containerC` I want `#containerD` to be position on its own. Would it be right if I set `#containerD` to have `position: relative` to sort of reset its relativity?